# Chrome Browser window closes automatically after test run

Tags: google-chrome, coded-ui-tests

I am developing coded ui tests(Using VS2012 Premium, Update 4) for my application. I have initially recorded my tests using IE8 and it works fine in in IE8. But When I try to run these tests in Chrome, the browser window automatically closes after the first test run and rest of the test fails. I am using the following code to launch chrome browser window

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
BrowserWindow window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(url));
window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
```

The same test methods run in IE8 without any error, but in Chrome the browser window closes automatically. If I run a single method it runs and closes window after the test run. I have verified other threads also, but nothing helped me to solve the issue.
I have already downloaded the selenium components required. Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue

I have tried to put the code in TestInitialize method but the result is same. Then I tried launching the browser using the Procees.Start method. This launches the browser but Coded UI is not able to find the browser window and it fails.

Comment: As part of your work around that you tried, be sure that after you launch the browser in the Process.Start method that you assign the right context to your Browser object in the test.  Could be that, in that case, it's still looking for the old window.

Comment: Check this: http://blogs.infosupport.com/how-to-reuse-your-browser-window-between-tests-in-codedui/

Answer (score 1):

The solution that refers to my blogpost will not work. This is a known limitation of codedUI cross browser functionality. Reuse of browser window cross test methods is only supported on IE
It is documented here:[Introducing cross browser testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx)

hope this helps,
Marcel